# Docker stopped working after updating Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was using Jenkins version 2.118 and docker was working fine. As soon as I upgraded the version to 2.128, docker stopped working. I got the following error:

```
$docker -v
/tmp/jenkins2434753345979877863.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins2434753345979877863.sh: docker: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

The /tmp/jenkinsxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.sh file that you reference is Jenkins’ temporary copy of your bash script that you wrote as part of your Jenkins project configuration. So either:

1) You changed your script that introduced some change in the docker invocation logic.

2) More likely, the docker daemon is no longer running. From a terminal (outside of Jenkins), run this command:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Then try to run your Jenkins project.

For Jenkins projects that I run, I have logic in the beginning that checks to see if the docker daemon is running, and starts it if not. Only then do I continue trying to use docker.

Comment: Iam not running any script. This is jenkins installed on kubenetes cluster. Iam just running $docker -v. I have installed this using helm.

Answer (score -1):

it was becuase jenkin's docker image has been updated by removing docker inside jetkin's docker image. so you have to go inside docker jetkin container like this :

> docker exec -ti -u root  bash

then, install docker

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     gnupg2 \
     software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable" && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install docker-ce
```

Now you can execute docker commands inside jenkins